# Can I "adopt something as a solution to something"?

Tags: expressions

Is it correct to say "take algorithm A as the basic method to solve the problem B"?

The [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/adopt) gives the following explanation:

> adopt somebody (as something)
>   (British English, politics) to choose somebody as a candidate in an election or as a representative

I want to know if it is correct to say "adopt A as B" in the context stated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's **adopt** algorithm A as the basic method to solve problem B.

The sentence seems okay to me. The meaning might be more "long lasting" compared with **take**. Compare:

> Let's **take** algorithm A and use it today, then switch to algorithm B tomorrow.

And

> Let's **adopt** algorithm A as our basic method and stick to it.

Of course, you can use **take** and likely even **adopt** in both sentences, I've only tried to express the possible slight difference of meaning.

When somebody **adopts** a child, it's usually for a long time, hence the use of the word might imply an intent to use the algorithm for a prolonged time.

Comment: Get it. Thank you very much. And I would like to ask a different question by the way. Every time I post a question, the first word doesn't appear. So when I post the above question, I have to type "Hi, Hello, everyone,...". What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: @ZongyiZhao: I had a similar problem, but only when I typed something like "Hi!" at the start of my post. It seems that the website's engine cuts hello messages.

Comment: @ZongyiZhao There is no need to say _hello_ every time you ask a question: This is a Q&A site and everything before the question is considered noise. The right way to be polite, on Stack Exchange, is voting the answers that helped you, and accept the answer that helped you more than others.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thank you. I appreciate the help from others, and I am willing to vote the answers. I will do that when my reputation is accumulated up to 15. Right now I have only 11 reputations. I am a newbie on this site.